# A tie knot algorithm puzzle

Tags: cipher

This is the actual way I memorize tie knots in life using just one "code word" for each.

- The four-in-hand knot has the code word BERT.
- Trinity has SRESITET.
- Eldredge has SESIETSAT.

Can you guess the thought process involved? All steps are things that are around in life and the internet.

Not sure what tags to add.

As a minor hint,

> The process is designed to minimize memory needed

Comment: I'm guessing a half Windsor is something like BESETT?

Comment: I think it was BRERT, but I'll get back to you on that